# How can I update a global python variable within the customJS function in bokeh?

Tags: python, variables, callback, slider

how is it possible to update the python variable `extern_python_variable` when the slider is moved in the example below? The value of `extern_python_variable` should always be f (the actual position of the slider). Thanks!

```
from bokeh.io import vform
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import Figure, output_file, show

output_file("callback.html")


x = [x*0.005 for x in range(0, 200)]
y = x

extern_python_variable=0

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

plot = Figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
        var data = source.get('data');
        var f = cb_obj.get('value')
        x = data['x']
        y = data['y']
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            y[i] = Math.pow(x[i], f)
        }
        source.trigger('change');
    """)

slider = Slider(start=0.1, end=4, value=1, step=.1, title="power", callback=callback)

test=source.to_df()

layout = vform(slider, plot)

show(layout)
```

Comment: The output of this code is a html file which contains javascript for the interaction machinery. So, it will run in a browser and it will run the javascript in your browser, it will not run any python routine. I am wondering what are you intending to do with the extern_python_variable? if you want to monitor the value of f, you can open a javascript console in the browser, and you can dump any information there using console.log(variable_to_monitor);

Comment: The code above should only be a simple example. In real, I want to save the rect attributes from a selection in python variables and I need the variables for further database oriented calculations which cannot be done in the customJS function.

Answer (score 2):

I see up to three ways of doing what you want:

1) Using the Bokeh Server you can respond to the tool events and sync with computations done in python. (See [Running a Bokeh Server](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.0/docs/user_guide/server.html))

2) If you still want to use static html pages, then, after a tool event, you can send data to a server (can be localhost) using a XMLHttpRequest (See [Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) ), which will then wait for a response from the server. The server can have a CGI python script (see [Python CGI Programming](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm)) reading the data sent by XMLHttpRequest and return some values to the CustomJS where the request was made.

3) A third rudimentary way could be opening an empty webpage and dump the data there using the document.write function (See [Window open() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)). Then you copy and paste the data in your python script or ipython notebook for analysis.

Comment: Great! Thanks Pablo. I will test your suggestion with the Bokeh Server.

Answer (score 0):

I like the method presented in the [widget](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/embed/widget.py) script in the bokeh embedded examples.

The CustomJS callback is only executed in the browser (no python code is executed). See [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.1/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#customjs-with-a-python-function)

As an example, using Bokeh server, you could add the following to your code to get the python callback:

```
def update(attr, old, new):
    # your custom python code

slider = Slider(start=0.1, end=4, value=1, step=.1, title="power")
slider.on_change('value', update)
```